# Assembly dependencies issue

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, .net-assembly

**Situation:**

I have tree projects (ZShared, ZSearcher and ZClient) where they will be referenced in each other.

ZShared is a common DLL assembly containing some styles and resources.

ZSearcher is also a DLL assembly with some WPF controls.

ZClient in theory can be anything (WPF app, Winforms, Excel etc.) for testing purposes I have made it as WPF app.

**Problem:**

When I reference ZShared in ZSearcher it produces two DLL files: ZShared.DLL and ZSearcher.DLL

When ZSearcher is referenced in ZClient, only the ZSearcher is copied to the ZClient folder. That can be solved by referencing the ZShared as well.

But I want the ZSearcher to be working as a standalone app. Like when ZSearcher is referenced then the dependecies should automatically follow.

Therefor I thought perhaps using reflection instead of referencing would solve the issue. But exact same issue happens with reflection.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException   HResult=0x80131501
>   Message='Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw
>   an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '18'.
>   Source=PresentationFramework
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at ZSearcher.SearcherWindow.InitializeComponent()
>   in
>   C:\Users\nn\Desktop\WorkSpaceVS\TestApplication\ZSearcher\SearcherWindow.xaml:line
>   1
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'ZShared, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

**Reproduction of issue:**

Create a `.NET-Framework` `C#` `DLL` assembly project (ZShared). This assembly only contains one `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ZSolidColorBrushRed" Color="Red"/>
    <Style x:Key="ZButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Create another `.NET-Framework` `C#` `DLL` assembly project (ZSearcher). This assembly contains one `Window` and once `Class`:

Searcher.cs class:

```
namespace ZSearcher
{
    public static class Searcher
    {
        public static object Search(string param)
        {
            var window = new SearcherWindow();
            window.ShowDialog();

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SearcherWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ZSearcher.SearcherWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Height="300" Width="500"
         Title="ZSearcher">

   <Window.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://Application:,,,/ZShared;component/ZResources.xaml"/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <TextBlock Text="SolidColorBrush test" Foreground="{DynamicResource ZSolidColorBrushRed}"/>
            <Button Content="Button style test" Style="{DynamicResource ZButtonStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Reference the ZShared.DLL in ZSearcher project.

Create a `.NET-Framework` `WPF` `C#` app. This app only contains the MainWindow.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ZClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ZClient" Width="400" Height="200">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open searcher" Click="OpenSearcher_Click" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using ZSearcher;

namespace ZClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenSearcher_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Referenced tester
            var referenceTest = Searcher.Search("Test");

            //Reflection tester
            var test = Test("Search");
        }

        private static object Test(string methodName)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\nn\Desktop\WorkSpaceVS\TestApplication\ZSearcher\bin\Debug\ZSearcher.DLL");
            var type = assembly.GetType("ZSearcher.Searcher");

            if (type == null) return null;
            var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            if (methodInfo == null) return null;
            var parametersArray = new object[] { "Test" };

            return methodInfo.Invoke(null, parametersArray);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How can I make this ZSearcher assembly to work as a standalone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MSBuild builds the solution, it needs to have a code-level reference in place between ZSearcher and ZShared in order to detect the dependency properly and copy it to the ZClient bin folder.

Some folks will create a dummy code reference to get around this issue.

```
using ZShared;

namespace ZSearcher
{
    public static class Searcher
    {
        static Searcher()
        {
            // Reference something from ZShared here...
        }

        public static object Search(string param)
        {
            var window = new SearcherWindow();
            window.ShowDialog();

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind blowing! When using reflection, no copying is involved. My assumption is that it is just reading the DLL from the absolute path. Why is the dummy reference needed for that ?

Comment: It's really weird. I haven't run into this issue personally, but I found lots of other folks here on SO and other places that have struggled with this for years across many versions of Visual Studio. It all comes down to black box magic within MSBuild. When there is an actual code reference between two assemblies then MSBuild will ensure they are copied properly. However, just dependency definitions are not enough. Most likely MSBuild is just trying to be too smart.